# React Native / Redux - Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I am just fetching the items from server and displaying them in the list component. The component structure is like

```
ServiceScreen(parent) -> ServicesList(child- used inside ServiceScreen) -> ServiceItem (child used inside ServicesList)
```

Every thing works well and it displays the services fetched but it gives me the following warning

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually
>   means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the
>   YellowBox component.

Code is as follows

**ServiceScreen.js**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.actions.fetchServices();
  }
    render() {
        const { isFetching } = this.props;
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ServicesList services={this.props.services} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
          </View>
        );
      }
```

**ServicesList.js**

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
            data={this.props.services}            
            renderItem={
                ({ item }) => 
                <ServiceItem navigation={this.props.navigation} item={item} />
            }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

**ServiceItem.js**

```
render() {
        const { item } = this.props;
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.singleService}>
                <Text>{item.service_name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
```

As I am using redux for state management, I have mapped the services
state to my ServiceScreen component. And I am passing down it to child
component.

Comment: Where are you calling the action that fetches the data? Please post the whole ServiceScreen component and your action that does the fetching.

Comment: I am dispatching the action in constructor to fetch services. I have updated the question. The action successfully dispatches and updates the state in redux store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should dispatch the action in componentDidMount. The constructor is called before the component is mounted, which is why you're seeing the error.

Here's a diagram with the react lifecycle. You should only call methods that change state in the "commit" phase.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. But I don't want to make the call to server every time the  component mounts? What can I do for that?

Comment: I tried dispatching the action in componentDidMount but as soon as the fetch is successfull the above Warning persists. I guess something else is causing this issue. It has to do some thing with Flat list I am using I guess.

Comment: Just an FYI: Please be aware that some of these lifecycle methods are only valid for React 16.3.0+.

Comment: It's not recommended to cause any side effects from the constructor, which calling a constructor definitely is. The lifecycle methods in green above are the only places considered "safe" to effect state/props now that async rendering is going to be part of React w/ the Fiber rewrite. Your top level component shouldn't be remounting regularly so that wouldn't be an issue. You could also check for data before dispatching the action.

Comment: If you hardcode the data in react state, do you still see the issue?

Comment: No, Actually I didn't try hardcoding the data to react state. I'll try the same and let you know if its working or not. Anyway many thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

This error is firing exactly when said in the yellowBox. Somewhere you trying to update already unmounted component.
I handled this issue by using temporary variable `componentIsMounted: bool` and wrapping `setState` method:

```
class SomeClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this._isComponentMounted = false;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isComponentMounted = true;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isComponentMounted = false;
  }

  setState(...args) {
    if (!this._isComponentMounted) {
      return;
    }

    super.setState(...args);
  }
}
```

Also, you should remember that you should not call state updates before the component get mounted (it`s not an alternative way - just an addition).